# how to handle a power down between related operations

Tags: c++, algorithm

I wonder how to handle a power down scenario. A function should send an event with the same id only once, but it can be called more than once with the same id (for example after a system restart). Id can be stored in a database (for example leveldb). Here is a naive approach which doesn't handle a power down scenario:

```
void T::fun(int id, Event ev)
{
   if(lastId.get() != id)
   {
      trigger->send(ev);
      //power down - ev has been sent but id is not saved.
      lastId.set(id);
   }    
}
```

How to handle a possible power down scenario ?

Comment: Does the order of the operations matter? Would it pose a problem to reverse them?

Comment: @GiladNaaman - Wouldn't that result in an equivalent problem (i.e. what happens if a "power-down" occurs after saving the last-set, but before sending the event)?

Comment: Essentially yes, but before writing the value you could try to read and validate it. Also, writing the value twice (say, to a file) might not be such a big problem compared to sending the event twice.